# Find the minimal polynomial over finite fields.

Tags: linear-transformations, finite-fields, minimal-polynomials

Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be a finite field with $q$ elements. Let $L(x)=a x^{q^2} +b x^q + cx\in \mathbb{F}_{q^3}[x]$. Assume that there exists an element $\beta\in\mathbb{F}_{q^3}$ such that 
$$\{L(x) \mid x \in \mathbb{F}_{q^3} \}=\{ \beta e \mid e\in \mathbb{F}_q\},$$
where $\mathbb{F}_q$ is the subfield of $\mathbb{F}_{q^3}$.

Denote $\{ \beta e \mid e\in \mathbb{F}_q\}=S_1$.It is well known that $L(x)$ is a linear transformation from $\mathbb{F}_{q^3}$ to $S_1$. I known that all the elements in $S_1$ must satisfy the polynomial $$H(x)=x^q-\beta^{q-1}x.$$

Denote $T(e)=\{x\in \mathbb{F}_{q^3} \mid L(x)=\beta e\}$ for $e \in \mathbb{F}_{q^3}$. The question is, given $e$, what is the minimal polynomial $f_e(x)$ that all the elements in $T(e)$ must satisfy, i.e., $f_e(x)=0$ for all $x \in T(e)$?

When we say "minimal", we mean the polynomial with the minmal degree. Because $g(x)=f(x)h(x)$ for any $h(x)\in\mathbb{F}_{q^3}$ is a such polynomial if $f(x)$ is.

Comment: Did you use $a$ and $\alpha$ in close proximity to each other? This aged mathematician with failing eyesight tells you that that is rather ill-advised.

Comment: @Lubin revised by replace $\alpha$ with $\beta$.

Comment: Thank you — the context made it clear what the situation was, but yet…

Comment: Are you saying all elements in $T(e)$ (for a given $e$) have the same degree over $\mathbb F_q$?

Comment: Please check the terms. I am not claiming that something is necessarily wrong, but with $x$ ranging over $\Bbb{F}_{q^3}$ only it feels strange to have both the linear term as well as the degree $q^3$ term because $x^{q^3}=x$ for all $x$ in this field.

Comment: Actually there is a problem related to that. Consider the polynomial 
$$\tilde{L}(x)=bx^{q^2}+(a+c)x.$$ Whenever $x\in\Bbb{F}_{q^3}$ we have $L(x)=\tilde{L}(x)$. Then consider the function from the algebraic closure to itself induced by $\tilde{L}$. That function is linear over the field $\Bbb{F}_{q^2}$. Because it is a degree $q^2$ polynomial (assuming $b\neq0\neq a+c$ here), its kernel, call it $V$, is a 1-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb{F}_{q^2}$. As $\Bbb{F}_{q^2}\cap\Bbb{F}_{q^3}=\Bbb{F}_q$, the intersection $V\cap \Bbb{F}_{q^3}$ is an at most 1-dimensional space over $\Bbb{F}_q$.

Comment: (cont'd) So, by rank-nullity, $\tilde{L}(x)$ takes at least $q^2$ distinct values when $x$ is ranging over $\Bbb{F}_{q^3}$. Meaning that the case of an image of size $q$ never happens, and we are looking at an empty claim.

Comment: I can probably say something non-immediate about this problem also (I have accumulated a bit of experience around this theme over the years), but I would like this sorted out first before I spend time on a problem that never occurs :-)

Comment: Also, I appreciate you tending to the problem @Lubin raised. He is senior to me (both academically and chronologically), but I don't have a very large screen either.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You are right. There are a few typos in the expression of $L(x)$. In fact, $L(x)$ is supposed to be any $q$-polynomials and it should be $L(x)=a x^{q^2} +b x^q + cx$. If the coefficients $a,b,c$ satisfy some conditions, then it will have $$\{L(x) \mid x \in \mathbb{F}_{q^3} \}=\{ \beta e \mid e\in \mathbb{F}_q\}.$$

Comment: @Cardioid_Ass_22 Probably, it is not true that all the elements have the same degree. I mean the degree of polynomial $f(x)$ such that $f(x)=0$ for ALL $x \in T(e)$, rather than for SOME $x \in T(e)$. I think it is different from the minimal polynomial of a element.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Now the question makes sense as it is possible that the kernel of $L$ is a 2-dimensional subspace over the subfield $\Bbb{F}_q$. I will think about this later. The sets $T(e)$ will be cosets of the kernel of $L$. I suspect the answer be not unlike that for the subset of elements of a fixed relative trace. But with $L$ being more complicated than the trace it is not clear cut. Wait, wouldn't the minimal polynomial have the form $L(x)+K$, with constant $K$? Hmm. I need to reread the question, sorry. Later today.

Comment: Hmm. I now think the answer is just $f_e(x)=L(x)+\beta e$, but may be I misunderstood something else. After all, there must be $q^2$ elements in the preimage.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I had the same result two days ago and cannot believe that it is so simple, just like $L(L^{-1}(x))-x=0$ for any $x$.